# Access Plist from MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, plist

I would like to create a plist and access it in my MonoTouch app. Plist file contains few values which i would like to access on a view.
I can create a plist but how to add it to Monotouch project and access values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your plist file in the Resource folder, in my example I named it to "Test.plist". Then simply load it as a NSDictionary like this,

```
NSDictionary dictionary = NSDictionary.FromFile ("Test.plist");
```

You can of course read the file using,

```
File.ReadAllText ("Test.plist")
```

also.

Remember to set the build action for the file to BundleResource.